# Uninitialized constant for ActiveRecord model in script/delayed_job, but not rake jobs:work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, delayed-job

I'm using Rails 2.3.8 with Ruby 1.8.7. I've made a new ActiveRecord model called `Foo` (generated using `script/generate model Foo ...`) with a method `#self.bar(x, y)` and in a controller I call `Foo.send_later(:bar, x, y)`. On my (Windows) development environment this works fine when I'm running `rake jobs:work`. On my (Linux) production environment, this also works if I'm running `rake jobs:work RAILS_ENV=production`, but if i'm running `RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start`, in the delayed_job.log I get

```
2011-02-19T12:27:11-0800: * [Worker(delayed_job host:myhost pid:3673)] acquired lock on Foo.bar
Could not load object for job: uninitialized constant Foo
2011-02-19T12:27:11-0800: * [JOB] delayed_job host:myhost pid:3673 completed after 0.0024
2011-02-19T12:27:11-0800: 1 jobs processed at 32.4446 j/s, 0 failed ...
```

My other delayed jobs work fine, only this new one has a problem. `Foo` is accessible from `script/console production`, and I've tried `touch tmp/restart.txt` or even restarting apache2 and then restarting the delayed_job script, but there was no change.

Has anyone seen this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

Use `rake jobs:work` in a `screen` session or, less hacky, run it using the `god` gem or `monit` so that if the process dies it will be "resurrected".